# Custom events in java,android? What does fireEvent do?

Tags: java, android, events

I found this link covering how to create a custom java event..
http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/custevent.html

The thing I dont get is.. what does the fireEvent method do?..and when is it called?.. is it called "automatically" as long as it extends from the EventObject class or how does it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The fireEvent method is not referenced from any other class or interface, so it will have to be invoked manually. (either by calling it in the code or by using reflection)